# How to display HTML content without Gutenberg blocks in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

My developer has updated my Wordpress to the latest and with it comes Gutenberg. I'm not a fan and I see every one of my HTML paragraphs now looks like this:

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Hello world!</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Needless to say, the `<!-- wp:paragraph -->` is confusing to me, especially because I write my content in HTML. It has the block tags around everything, including images. I don't want to deal with these.

I tried using this plugin to disable Gutenberg entirely: https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ but the Gutenberg paragraph tags remain. How can I revert my HTML content back to how it was before this awful Gutenberg update?

Comment: That `<!-- wp:paragraph -->` bit is an [HTML comment](https://html.com/tags/comment-tag/) and won't affect your code in any way. You can just ignore it and add your custom code as usual.

Comment: But it’s confusing, especially if you have a lot of content and every paragraph opens and closes this way. I write in HTML editor so all I see are hundreds of these paragraph blocks. Is there no way to revert back to the old system where I only had to deal with <p> and </p>?

Comment: You could downgrade your site to any version previous to WordPress 5.0 but I don't really advise that as you'd be leaving your site open to attacks. It's not worth the risk IMO.